# Is the CRC algorithm of Office implemented in C#

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography, ms-office

I am looking for an implementation of the crc algorithm defined by Microsoft Office

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd922675.aspx

Is it already implemented somewhere?

Comment: Do you need source code of the implemenation or just the ability to calculate the checksum from c#?

Comment: Source code is good but I can use another library.

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, but i think if you refine your search to look for Microsoft Office CRC [SALT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) you will have better luck.

In short the CRC algorithme should be the same as any other, but some times programs have their own SALT to "spice" up the hash algorithme.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but 15 minutes and the office article suggests that this should do the trick. Given that the original source allows the caller to seed the algorithm with whatever starting value they want, There's no guarantee that I see, that the results will match whatever you're looking for: MS Office could seed the CRC computation with 32 bits of random entropy. Nothing says that computation is to be seeded with an initial value of 0.

```
public class MsoCrc32
{
  private const int BUFFER_SIZE =  4096 ;
  private static readonly uint[] cache ;

  public uint Value { get ; private set ; }

  public void Add( byte[] bytes )
  {
    foreach ( byte octet in bytes )
    {
      uint i = ( Value >> 24 ) ^ octet ;

      Value <<= 8        ;
      Value  ^= cache[i] ;

    }

    return ;
  }
  public void Add( Stream s )
  {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE] ;
    int    bufl   = 0 ;

    while ( (bufl=s.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length)) > 0 )
    {
      Add( buffer ) ;
    }

    return ;
  }

  public MsoCrc32() : this(0)
  {
  }
  public MsoCrc32( int value )
  {
    this.Value = (uint) value ;
  }
  static MsoCrc32()
  {
    cache = InitCache();
    return ;
  }

  private static uint[] InitCache()
  {
    uint[] cacheInstance = new uint[256] ;

    for ( uint i = 0 ; i < cache.Length ; ++i )
    {
      uint value = i << 24 ;

      for ( uint j = 0 ; j < 8 ; ++j )
      {
        value <<= 1 ;
        if ( 0x80000000 == (value&0x80000000) )
        {
          value  ^= 0xAF000000 ;
        }
      }

      value &= 0xFFFF0000 ;

      cacheInstance[i] = value ;

    }

    return cacheInstance ;
  }

}
```